# How to handle QUORUM consistency in 4 node, 2 DC Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have a four node, two Data Center cassandra 1.1.1 cluster.
My keyspace is RF 2 per Data center, giving me complete copy of data on each node.
The cluster is for a vendor product, which uses r/w consistency of QUORUM. With this config I can only handle the loss of one node.... How can I tweak it to handle the loss of a data center?

Answer (score 4):

Unless your data centers are in the same physical location, your network overhead is going to be terrible with this configuration.  The reason is because quorum consistency will not pay attention to DC when it's comparing replicas.  So you will frequently have to cross data center lines before acking a read or write.  Switching to local quorum would solve the latency issue but would effectively cause a data center to go down if one node goes down.  However, as long as both nodes in the second DC are up (and your app can handle this properly), you will still be up and running.

Having said that, the general rule of thumb is that 3 nodes is the bare minimum per data center.  If you add a node to each data center and switch to local quorum R/W, you can lose one node in each DC and still have that DC operational, or you can lose an entire DC with the other remaining operational.

Comment: The vendor refuses to switch from QUORUM to LOCAL_QUORUM. How can I get a quorum r/w with a DC down?  Add another node on demand if DC is down??

Comment: Adding a node on the fly is not a great option because your token ownership will get screwed up, and you'll be down during bootstrap anyway.  What parts of the system are in your control?

Comment: Well, regarding tokens, I'm doing replication factor 2 per DC now.  Could I add a phantom/virtual DC node, but its really in same DC as the others... just brainstorming.  The cluster and RF is in my control, but not the vendor cass client code which is using RC QUORUM.

Comment: A couple things: 1. RF doesn't determine token ownership, just how many replicas get created. You still have only one "owner". 2. If the client doesn't use node auto-discovery or it can be turned off, you can set up your second DC like an analytics cluster (see [my presentation on the topic](http://www.slideshare.net/rastrick/presentation-12982302)).  Then you only write to one DC, while the other gets a set of replicas that can be used for failover.  Since the client is using quorum, you need to hide the second DC from it, and only use that DC when your first fails.